# Node: Request context when invoked by other lambda function

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I'm building an application which consists of multiple lambda functions and which will be part of an already existing application landscape.

**My issue on this**: I don't know how to extend my logs with a unique trace id in an easy fashion, so that all logs regarding one transaction are logged with the same id.

To give some insight on one of the processes:

- `lambda #1` is using express and is exposing an API via ApiGateway. Within one 'transaction' it is also queuing some events in SQS.
- `lambda #2` is polling the queue regularly and is doing some other work. Afterwards it is calling `lambda #1` directly to finish the transaction.

So the whole flow: `some other app` --Request with TraceID--> `ApiGateway` -> `lambda #1` -> `SQS` -> `lambda #2` -> `lambda #1`.

**What I did until now**
I'm using [request-context](https://github.com/michaelkrone/request-context) for tracing requests. But thats just working if you got a valid request context. So I can't log with the correct trace id on `lambda #1` after it was called at the last stage by `lambda #2` (which is submitting the trace id in its request).

The invocation point for `lambda #1` looks like this:

```
export function handler(event: any, context: any) {
  if (event.targetAction) {
    switch (event.targetAction as TargetAction) {
      // invocation by lambda #2 will end up here
      // we got no request context for express
      case TargetAction.FINISH_TRANSACTION:
        /** do some other work **/
        return;
      default:
      /** **/
    }
  }
  return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
}
```

How do I get my trace-id to the logs in this case?

**Other thoughts**:

- I could do a workaround and add a new route to `lambda #1` and also submit a path & http method to my event and then pass it to the proxy handler so we end up on an express route. Seems like a bad solution.

I'm very glad for every help or thought on this, even if its pointing me in some complete other direction.

**Edit**

For now I'm going with the workaround which is working fine. I've created a router which is for internal usage. This is how the handler looks like if anyone is interested:

```
export function handler(event: any, context: any) {
if (event.targetAction) {
  switch (event.targetAction as TargetAction) {
     case TargetAction.UPDATE_TRANSACTION:
        const updateEvent: ExpressProxyEvent = {
           path: '/internal/update-transaction',
           headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'x-trace-id': event.xtraceId,
              'x-internal-router-secret': Constants.INTERNAL_ROUTER_SECRET
           },
           body: JSON.stringify(event),
           httpMethod: 'POST'
         };
         event = updateEvent;
         break;
      case /** **/
    }
    return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
}
```

With this the traceId can be set in the request-context middleware when invoked directly by another lambda function (the event could also be correctly created in `lambda #2`, but then it needs to know the path & method for the internal router in `lambda #1`).

Nevertheless I'm still interested in an independent solution.

Comment: why do you want to hide it?